# PHP strip_tags - splitting tags into an array

Tags: php

I have a big html content entry. I need to split only the plain text into separate entries in an array, so that I can run it through a translation tool and then replace it into the original html.

I've managed to clean it out and then split lines into an array, but the text `...to do this <a href="#" title="blah">click here</a>` comes back as `...to do this click here`.

doing a `str_replace` on that text won't match anymore because of the `a` tag.

So, I need a way to turn the tags that would normally be stripped using `strip_tags` into an inserted value that i can use to explode the string with.

any suggestions?

Comment: Just use DOM to access each section.

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel :) http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Instead of SimpleHtmlDom use one of these http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php its part of PHP and will work all the time and will not tie your code to a 3rd party library which you don't really need to achieve this.

Comment: thanks. am looking into DOM as it's not something i'm familiar with. I can't guarantee the html will be valid as it's user input via a WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 0):

okay, I've figured it out and DOM is more complicated than I need in this instance.

The simpler solution was to use a regex match to find all the tags and then break the html down by those.

```
preg_split('/<.+?>/', $html);
```

This leaves just the text. As I don't need any of the tag info, this should be quicker to process as well.